# Show div if Magento product is in certain category

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I'm trying to achieve the following in Magento (1.9.2) in a phtml file:

I would like to display certain html on the product page only if the product is (also) in category id 350.

The product is in many categories. I don't want to show the html when the product is viewed necessarily from a specific category path.

So someone can visit the product page on domain.com/productURL without getting there from a specific category.

What's important is that if that product is ALSO (not only) in category id 350, among other categories it's in, than show a certain div. If not, show a different div.

I'm tying to put an if statement in a phtml file that is already set up, but I don't seem to get the if statement right.

Answer (score 1):

To check either product is in category id 350 or not, you can use the following condition in product `view.phtml` file

```
if(in_array(350, $_product->getCategoryIds()))
```

You can use the following code to get category id when the product has viewed from a specific category path

```
Mage::registry('current_category')->getId()
```

You can add your logic by play with these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code on your theme `view.phtml` file

```
<?php 
   if($_product->getCategoryId()==350){
     your custom here
   }
?>
```